# Find the focus, vertex, latus rectum of the parabola

Tags: analytic-geometry

The problem is,

> Find the focus, equation of directrix, vertex, length of latus rectum of the parabola given by, $$\left(\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma\right)^2=Ax+By+C$$

I am stuck with the problem for quite sometime but still don't know how to begin. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is "rectum" seriously a mathematical word? Why am I just now finding out about this?!

Comment: @crash yes it is, you'd know if you had taken up conics

Comment: @G-man I'd gladly have taken up the conics rather than take anything up the rectum. :D

Comment: I'd have upvoted that comment but the tooltip saying "this comment adds something useful to the post" stops me from doing that.

Comment: @user170039 , this is problem is for the most part, mechanical and the results are quite complicated, especially so for the focus. Why do you want to do this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First simplify the parabola equation to a general $2^{nd}$ degree equation:
$$(\alpha x+\beta y)^2+(2\beta\gamma - B)y+(2\alpha\gamma-A)x+\gamma^2-C=0$$

Now let $2g=2\alpha\gamma-A$,$2f=2\beta\gamma - B$ and $d=\gamma^2-C$ and then substitute in the equation:
$$(\alpha x+\beta y)^2=-2fy-2gx-d$$
Let $\exists\lambda\in\mathbb R$ such that :
$$(\alpha x+\beta y+\lambda)^2=2(\alpha\lambda-g)x+2(\beta\lambda-f)y+\lambda^2-d$$
Note that the equation of any parabola can be written in the form:
$$(distance\;from\;axis)^2=(length\;of\;latus\;rectum)\times(distance\;from\;tangent\;at\;vertex)$$
For the lines on the LHS and RHS to be perpendicular to each other,
$$\frac \alpha\beta\times\frac{\alpha\lambda-g}{\beta\lambda-f}=-1\implies \lambda=\frac{\alpha g+\beta f}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$$
Now we rewrite our equation as:
$$\left( \frac{\alpha x+\beta y+\lambda}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}} \right)^2=\frac{2\sqrt{(\alpha\lambda-g)^2+(\beta\lambda-f)^2}}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}\times\frac{2(\alpha\lambda-g)x+2(\beta\lambda-f)y+\lambda^2-d}{2\sqrt{(\alpha\lambda-g)^2+(\beta\lambda-f)^2}}$$

From here we can make several conclusions:

The equation of the axis is:$$\alpha x+\beta y +\lambda=0\tag{i}$$

The equation of tangent at vertex is:$$2(\alpha\lambda-g)x+2(\beta\lambda-f)y+\lambda^2-d=0\tag{ii}$$
From the intersection of above 2 lines, the vertex coordinates are:$$\left( \frac{2f\lambda-\beta\lambda^2-\beta d}{2(\beta g- \alpha f)}\;,\;\frac{2g\lambda-\alpha\lambda^2-\alpha d}{-2(\beta g- \alpha f)} \right)\tag{iii}$$
The lentgh of latus rectum is $$L=\frac{2\sqrt{(\alpha\lambda-g)^2+(\beta\lambda-f)^2}}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}\tag{iv}$$